Understanding the difference between limit point compact and compact
I have come across a counter example for showing a set that is limit point compact is not necessarily compact, however I cannot quite see how the example shows the result.
The definitions I am working with are as follows:
Compact set: Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. Then X is called a compact set if every open cover of X is called compact if every open cover of X has a finite subcover which also covers X.
Limit point compact: A topological space X is called limit point compact if every infinite subset of X has a limit point.
The counter example given is simple. Just take $Y = $ { $ a,b $ }  and equip it with indiscrete topology. Then $X = \mathbb{N} \times Y$ is limit point compact. This is actually very similar to the example given on wikipedia here.
However I cannot quite see how this example shows that the set $X$ is limit point compact. If I take $x = (3,b)$ which should surely be in $X$, what would all open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ be?
I understand that to show $x$ is a limit point and so show limit point compactness we should have $U \cap X - $ { $x$ } $ \neq \emptyset $, but I cannot convince myself what all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ will be. Can someone please enlighten me? Since $Y$ has the discrete topology and so the only non-empty open set in $Y$ is $Y$ itself. Does this mean that in the product topology $ \mathbb{N} \times Y$, $(3,a)$ would also be a neighborhood of $(3,b)$?
I imagine that $X$ is not compact since a possible countable cover could be one based on a collection of subsets consisting individual elements of $\mathbb{N}$ for which no finite collection can be found to entirely cover $\mathbb{N}$.

The topology given on $\Bbb{N}$ is the discrete topology.
So the open sets in $X$ are of the form $U\times Y$ where $U$ is open in $\Bbb{N}$.
Take any point in your infinite set, say $(3,b)$.
Note that any open set containing $(3,b)$ will also contain $(3,a)$.
So $(3,a)$ is a limit point of your collection.
(Actually you don't need an infinite collection to begin with, any point has a limit point in this space).
To show that $X$ is not compact, use the fact that the topology on $\Bbb{N}$ is discrete.

Thanks - I understand the logic following on from $\mathbb{N}$ having the discrete topology. But how do I know it carries the discrete topology? I feel like I am missing the obvious but I don't see where this is necessarily the case.

There are two topologies that you can give to any non empty set, the discrete topology and the indiscrete topology. Here giving $\Bbb{N}$ the indiscrete topology won't help you. Because then the space will be compact. So it's natural to work with the discrete topology.
